# PhpStorm Formatter: Exclude all files except one

Tags: phpstorm, webstorm, glob

In PhpStorm, where one specifies the files/directories that the formatter should **not** format, I need to include all HTML files except one. The formatter accepts instructions using glob patterns, and so, *.html specifies that I do not want any files ending with the html extension to be formatted.

How do I translate "Do not format any HTML file ***except for*** test.html" into a glob patter?

**Context**
The project I am working on is ages old and is incredibly fragile. When PhpStorm formats the HTML files, which also include PHP, it always breaks them. And these files are often several thousands of lines long, and so it's not worth going through and fixing the issues. However, I want to create a test HTML file where I can format the select divs or portions of HTML I copy over.

The only issue is that I can't figure out how to convey this to PhpStorm because it just has a single input field where you can specify files and directories with glob patterns. Sounds great, until you're in my situation. From what I've read, glob patterns are only *inclusive*. I've seen some examples where Bash users deduct sets, however, I'm not in bash. I'm just passing patterns in the way I would assign tags to this post.

Comment: So why not place such a file in a separate folder and only allow formatting there?

Comment: I might have to do that... But if there is an answer specifically about how to write such a glob pattern, I'd like to learn it.